# change the fps of trackers in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, video-processing, opencv3.0, object-detection

I am using OpenCV 3.4.1 tracking classes in C++ Visual Studio 2015. Among the 8 trackers available in OpenCv, I am using mainly KCF,CSRT and MEDIANFLOW and the fps of these tracking algorithms are 30,4,4 respectively. I would like to know whether I can change the fps of these so that the videos are processed faster. What am I doing wrong here? Or anybody knows how to increase the fps of CSRT/MEDIANFLOW to 30(same as KCF)?

In my code, KCF is faster than CSRT and MEDIANFLOW , but the tracking performance/accuracy is not as good as CSRT. But the processing speed of KCF is really good, because of its high fps.

```
    #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <map>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    vector<string> trackerTypes = { "BOOSTING", "MIL", "KCF", "TLD", "MEDIANFLOW", "GOTURN", "MOSSE", "CSRT" };

    // create tracker by name
    Ptr<Tracker> createTrackerByName(string trackerType)
    {
        Ptr<Tracker> tracker;
        if (trackerType == trackerTypes[0])
            tracker = TrackerBoosting::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[1])
            tracker = TrackerMIL::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[2])
            tracker = TrackerKCF::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[3])
            tracker = TrackerTLD::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[4])
            tracker = TrackerMedianFlow::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[5])
            tracker = TrackerGOTURN::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[6])
            tracker = TrackerMOSSE::create();
        else if (trackerType == trackerTypes[7])
            tracker = TrackerCSRT::create();
        else {
            cout << "Incorrect tracker name" << endl;
            cout << "Available trackers are: " << endl;
            for (vector<string>::iterator it = trackerTypes.begin(); it != trackerTypes.end(); ++it)
                std::cout << " " << *it << endl;
        }
        return tracker;
    }

    int main(int argc, char * argv[])
    {
        const int N = 2;
        double xcordinate = 0;
        double ycordinate = 0;
        double Xvalue = 0;
        double Yvalue = 0;
        double firstFrameY[10] = {};
        double remainFrameY[10] = {};
        double firstFrameX[10] = {};
        double remainFrameX[10] = {};


        string trackerType = "CSRT";
        cout << "The Selected tracker is " << trackerType << endl;

        string videoPath = "SS-100_random11sec_Trim.mp4";
        vector<Rect> bboxes;
        Mat frame;
        cv::VideoCapture cap(videoPath);

        cap >> frame;
        bool showCrosshair = true;
        bool fromCenter = false;

        cout << "Enter the value of X-cordinate\n";
        cin >> xcordinate;
        cout << "Enter the value of Y-cordinate\n";
        cin >> ycordinate;
        cv::selectROIs("MultiTracker", frame, bboxes, showCrosshair, fromCenter);

        if (bboxes.size() < 1)
            return 0;

        Ptr<MultiTracker> multiTracker = cv::MultiTracker::create();

        for (int i = 0; i < bboxes.size(); i++)
            multiTracker->add(createTrackerByName(trackerType), frame, Rect2d(bboxes[i]));

        cout << "Started tracking, press ESC to quit." << endl;

        int m = 0;

        while (cap.isOpened())
        {

            cap >> frame;
            if (frame.empty()) break;
            multiTracker->update(frame);
            for (unsigned i = 0; i < multiTracker->getObjects().size(); i++)
            {
                rectangle(frame, multiTracker->getObjects()[i], colors[i], 2, 1);
                bboxes[i] = multiTracker->getObjects()[i];
                //cout << "The Co-ordinates: " << bboxes[i] << endl;
                outputFile << std::left << bboxes[i].x <<',' << std::right << bboxes[i].y << '\n';  
            }

            if (m == 0)  //for saving the reference values
            {
                for (int i = 0; i< N; i++)
                {
                    firstFrameY[i] = bboxes[i].y;
                    remainFrameY[i] = bboxes[i].y;
                    firstFrameX[i] = bboxes[i].x;
                    remainFrameX[i] = bboxes[i].x;
                }
                m++;

            }

            else
            {
                //get the y values into an array and pass it below
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                {
                    remainFrameY[i] = bboxes[i].y;
                    remainFrameX[i] = bboxes[i].x;
                }
            }

Xvalue = getTheEquationX(firstFrameX, remainFrameX, xcordinate, TrackedX);
        Yvalue = getTheEquationY(firstFrameY, remainFrameY, ycordinate, TrackedY);

        cropObject(Xvalue, Yvalue, frame, count_4);

            resize(frame, frame, Size(1280, 720), 0, 0, INTER_CUBIC);
            imshow("MultiTracker", frame);

            if (waitKey(1) == 27) break; 

        }
```